# How do to manually create an Android savegame (snapshot) conflict?

Tags: android, c++, save, conflict, snapshot

I've implemented a cloud save mechanism in my game using the android c++ Snapshot class. It saves and loads perfectly. However, I'm trying to set up a test case that will cause a conflict. But I can't work out how to do it. I keep hearing lots of very wooly "that one needs to be off line and this one needs to save" etc. But no specifics. Anyone know how to generate a conflict with 2 devices, A and B?

Device A
Commits - All works fine, no conflict detected by API.

Device B
Commits - All works fine, no conflict detect by API, Device A's game gets overwritten.

Maybe one of the devices has to be off-line during a commit?

Here's what I'm using to detect conflicts, none are ever detected:

```
GPlusMgr::Get().GetGameServices()->Snapshots().Open(gpg::DataSource::CACHE_OR_NETWORK, Filename.ToASCII(), gpg::SnapshotConflictPolicy::MANUAL, [this](gpg::SnapshotManager::OpenResponse res)
{
    if (res.conflict_id != "")
    {
        // Do scary conflict resolution dance.
    }
    else
    {
        // No conflict, just save to cloud.
    }
```

Many thanks,

Steve.

Answer (score 0):

To create a conflict you need following situation

- A and B load the same game state
- A and B change the game state
- A and B want to save their state in the cloud

[image]

A commits first. When B tries to commit, it will either overwrite A's changes or detect, that the state changed. B's changes don't base on the current snapshot but on an earlier state. B produces a conflict.

Comment: Hi Thomas, (updated the question with additional details). It doesn't appear to work like that when implemented on Android. Have you tried this on an Android device? No conflicts are detected with that scenario. Thanks.